# How can i return cursors from oracle user defined functions

Tags: plsql

How can i return cursors from oracle user defined functions

Like

My function should take some inputs or no inputs and return me output in a cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101178/18747) to a different question for an example.