# Return multiple rows from oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to return multiple rows from stored procedure in oracle.How will i do that ??
Can any one explain me with two scenarios

1.Select all rows in a table.

2.Select rows through depending on the arguments passed.

Im new to oracle..

Comment: Here is the answer to your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101033/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-the-stored-procedure-oracle-pl-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create [Ref Cursor](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Working-with-REF-CURSOR-in-PL-SQL/) so that your procedure can return a record set (multiple rows)

Comment: A ref cursor isn't the only option. A pipelined (table) function can also be used to return a result set.

Comment: I got it through Ref Cursor,but i'm eager to know what is the concept of pipelined (table) function with simple example

Comment: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html looks like a informative tutorial for oracle pipelined functions if you are really interested, @ksg.