# How to retrieve multiple rows from stored procedure with Scala?

Tags: database, scala, stored-procedures, squeryl

Say you have a stored procedure or function returning multiple rows, as discussed in [How to return multiple rows from the stored procedure? (Oracle PL/SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101033/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-the-stored-procedure-oracle-pl-sql)

What would be a good way, using Scala, to "select * from table (all_emps);" (taken from URL above) and read the multiple rows of data that would be the result?

As far as I can see it is not possible to do this using Squeryl. Is there a scalaified tool like Squeryl that I can use, or do I have to drop to JDBC?

Answer (score 2):

Functions that return tables are an Oracle specific feature, I doubt an ORM (be it Scala or even Java) would have support for such a proprietary extension. 
So I think you're more or less on your own :). 
Probably the easiest way is to use a plain JDBC java.sql.Statement and execute "select * from table (all_emps)" with the executeQuery method.

Comment: PostgreSQL has the same thing: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/callproc.html - but I see what you mean, JDBC is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To address the second part of your question about a way to select from table in a more scala-esque way, I am using [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/). Quoting from their example documentation:

```
case class Coffee(name: String, supID: Int, price: Double)

implicit val getCoffeeResult = GetResult(r => Coffee(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))

Database.forURL("...") withSession {
Seq(
Coffee("Colombian", 101, 7.99),
Coffee("Colombian_Decaf", 101, 8.99),
Coffee("French_Roast_Decaf", 49, 9.99)
).foreach(c => sqlu"""
insert into coffees values (${c.name}, ${c.supID}, ${c.price})
""").execute)

val sup = 101
val q = sql"select * from coffees where sup_id = $sup".as[Coffee]
// A bind variable to prevent SQL injection ^
q.foreach(println)
}
```

Though I am not sure how it's dealing (if at all) with stored procs/functions.