# create the pl/sql which returns the list of procedures in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to list procedures and triggers in the database, but I have to use procedure or function to do so.

This query returns exactly what I need, but I need to get the same results using PL/SQL.

```
select *
  from all_source
 where type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

this query returns exactly what I need, but I have to get the same results using PL/SQL.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare record all_source%ROWTYPE
begin
select * into record from all_source where type = ?
end;
```

Comment: declare record varchar
begin
select * into record from all_source where type = procedure
end;    //this didn't work

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101033/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-the-stored-procedure-oracle-pl-sql

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below procedure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE get_proc_list(
          i_type IN VARCHAR2,
          o_result OUT sys_refcursor)
IS
     l_type VARCHAR2(10) := UPPER(i_type);
BEGIN
    OPEN o_result FOR
    SELECT * FROM all_source
    WHERE  TYPE = l_type;
END;
```

To Execute the procedure,

```
var o_result refcursor;
EXECUTE get_proc_list('procedure',:o_result);
print o_result;
```

Comment: Ok. So, to execute it i should use execute get_proc_list('procedure') ?? I need one more argument.. Thank you for your time

Comment: @user1845928, I have modified the answer to add execution steps.

Comment: Great. Thank you. Can you tell me why I am not getting the list of triggers when I use parameter 'trigger' instead of 'procedure' ??

Comment: You will surely get the list of triggers if you have trigger in your schema. try like this,         
 
`EXECUTE get_proc_list('trigger',:o_result);`