# How to Dynamically Name Table in Oracle SQL Select Statement?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, plsql

i would like to return all rows and fields from a table, where neither the tablename nor the fieldnames are known in advance. Something like:

`select * from [TABLENAME]`

this other method looks promising, but `select * from test_cursor` gives "attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known..."
https://stackoverflow.com/a/101064/209942

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` seems promising, but i read that returning multiple rows requires a cursor, and i can't find an example.

Prefer a solution that's very simple and fast (ie, would like to avoid row-by-row processing).

Would like to avoid creating a function or procedure, but maybe that's unavoidable. Maybe i need to use a table function?

Maybe something like the following?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetTable(table_name CHAR)

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE temp_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM :1)' USING table_name;

END;

SELECT * FROM table (temp_table)
```

thx

Comment: Check package [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS058), there you can do full dynamic SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not require any knowledge of field types or number.

The short answer is:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE temp_table AS (SELECT * FROM ' ||table_name||')';

SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

The long answer is:

```
DROP TABLE TEMP_TABLE;

DECLARE table_name VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN
  table_name := 'subreports';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE temp_table AS (SELECT * FROM ' ||table_name||')';
END;

SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

Or, as a procedure (anyone, correct my syntax):

```
create procedure GetTable (table_name in VARCHAR2(200), result_set out sys_refcursor)
   is
   begin
    DROP TABLE TEMP_TABLE PURGE;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE temp_table AS (SELECT * FROM ' ||table_name||')';
      open result_set for select * from temp_table;
   end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I create a variable by using user_tables.which is store to table name.

```
  Create procedure dynamic_tab_name(tab_name user_tables.table.name%type)
  As
     Type refc is ref cursor;
     Cur refc;
     Result varchar2(30);
    Begin
       Open cur for 'select a from'|| tab_name;
       Fetch cur into result;       
       dbms_output. put_line(result);
       Close cur;
    End;
```

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part of your requirement is the **datatype consistency** of the columns you want to get, and **number of columns** that may be different between each tablename you want to select.

For your question, you could use:

1. dynamic SQL and  [Global Temporary Table](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables) : only if fieldname1 and fieldname2 always have datatype match col1 and col2 of your global_temp (you must create global_temp table first).

   ```
   delete global_temp;
   sql_stmt := 'insert into global_temp(col1,col2) 
                SELECT '|| fieldname1 || ',' || fieldname2
                ||' FROM ' || var_table_name;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
   select * from global_temp; --do any thing with result temp table
   ```
2. [dynamic SQL into records](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/11_dynam.htm#i13130) (loop each row to get results): go to link, search `emp_rec`