# PL/SQL: Select function result with multiple rows from dual

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I select a function result with multiple rows from dual in PL/SQL?

```
SELECT multipleRowsFunction() AS multiple FROM dual;
```

or

```
BEGIN
  SELECT multipleRowsFunction() INTO multiple FROM dual;
END;
```

Are there any alternatives to DUAL for this purpose?

Comment: Unsure of exactly what you want. Nevertheless, have a look at this question and see if it give you any clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101033/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-the-stored-procedure-oracle-pl-sql. Note it's asking a different question but the answers seem to relate to the part of the question that you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your function, your best bet is

```
select * from table(multipleRowsFunction);
```

In a PL/SQL block, you do not need `select ... from dual`; just write

```
begin
  multiple := multipleRowsFunction;
end;
```