# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")"

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, web-applications

I am creating a web app which requires connecting to a database and getting the catagories of various types of reports. I am getting a weird error when it comes to executing my SQL via storedproc in java. `SELECT * FROM RPT_CTGR;` is the sql I submit but when I look at the stack trace it comes back as this:

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call SELECT * FROM RPT_CTGR;(?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 38:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec as between || indicator multiset member
   submultiset

    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:969)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1003)
    org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:144)
    org.ifmc.qies.reportaudit.impl.CataImpl.search(CataImpl.java:59)
    org.ifmc.qies.reportaudit.web.CataAction.execute(CataAction.java:31)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Which for some reason is appending the extra "(?)" to the end of my statement which causes the error. Any ideas?

Code

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.ifmc.qies.reportaudit.dao.CataDao;
import org.ifmc.qies.reportaudit.model.Catagory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

public class CataImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements CataDao {
    protected static ApplicationContext ctx = null;
//BaseStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure
    public class CataProc extends BaseStoredProcedure{

        public CataProc(DataSource ds, String name) {
            super(ds,name);
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(getSql());
            declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("catagories", OracleTypes.CURSOR,
                    new RowMapper() {
                        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                                throws SQLException {

                            Catagory t = new Catagory();
                            t.setCatId(rs.getString(1));
                            t.setCat_name(rs.getString(2));
                            System.out.println(t.getCat_name());
                            return t;
                        }
                    }));
        }


    }
@Override
    public List search() {
    String[] paths = {"V:path/to/applicationcontext.xml"};
    Map params=new HashMap();
    ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(paths);
    DataSource ds = (DriverManagerDataSource)ctx.getBean("dataSource");
        CataProc proc = new CataProc(ds,"SELECT * FROM RPT_CTGR;");
        Map results = proc.execute(params);
        List catagory = (List)results.get("catagories");
        //Test
        System.out.println(catagory.get(1).toString());
        return catagory;
    }



}
```

I get all my `print` statements except for the `catagories.get(1).toString` to return properly the SQL I submitted

Comment: Post the COMPLETE stack trace please

Comment: What is `declareParameter`?  Sounds like that is adding the `(?)` at the end of the statement.  Also, is the semicolon redundant?  IIRC it used to be required that you omit semicolons but it's been a long time so I'm not sure.

Comment: declareParameter does as it says. declares that catagories will be the parameter that holds the output of the sql, in this case the catagory object. But I did take it out,as it did seem unnecessary  but the same issue happens just instead of (?) its just (). I took out the sqloutparameter but that didn't change anything. Also, just from this website https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-StoredProcedure, it does say I have to have that declare parameter for every new sqlparameter.

Comment: It seems that you are sending a request to call a store procedure and you are sending a select statement instead. You are sending `SELECT * FROM RPT_CTGR;` as the *name* of the Store Procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `Store Procedure` in your Oracle Database which executes your `SELECT` statement.
You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101033/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-the-stored-procedure-oracle-pl-sql) as reference on how to do it.

E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getCatagories(categories in out sys_refcursor) is
  ...
  SELECT * FROM RPT_CTGR;
  ...
```

After that, you need to call the store procedure by its name.

```
public List search() {
  ...
  DataSource ds = (DriverManagerDataSource) ctx.getBean("dataSource");
  CataProc proc = new CataProc(ds,"getCatagories");
  Map results = proc.execute(params);
  List catagory = (List)results.get("catagories");
  ... 
}
```