# can i use join in stored procedures - oracle database

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have two tables product and condition where `product_id` is primary key of product and its foreign key in condition.

```
product
product_id name
1          eggs
2          milk

condition
product_id condition_name
1            new
2            bad
1            normal
```

I need a procedure which can give me the name of the all product which is not have bad condition.

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure? A simple query is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use single query as follows:

```
select p.name
  from product p
where not exists (select 1 from condition c where p.product_id = c.product_id
and c.condition_name = 'bad');
```

Comment: no, sorry i dont need query, i know the query, but i need a procedure

Comment: Use this query in the procedure. Then your procedure will be ready.

Comment: i am trying it /

Comment: A stored procedure cannot return values with RETURN keyword (but a stored function can). A stored procedure can only return values in OUT parameter. How do you plan to use the stored procedure OUT parameter ? Please give details about host language and API. See PL/SQL examples in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101033/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-the-stored-procedure-oracle-pl-sql.